# Mysql Group Replication--why the maximum number of MySQL servers in a group is 9 server

Tags: mysql

I'm looking the Mysql Group Replication reference manual(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-frequently-asked-questions.html).

And the manual just say that **a group can consist of maximum 9 servers.  Attempting to add another server to a group with 9 members causes the request to join to be refused.** without any explanation.

In my personal perspective, the group can contain any number of servers. I can't understand why the maximum number of servers in a group is 9. Can any one give some explanation of such restriction.

Comment: Are you sure you're thinking of *InnoDB Group Replication* members?  This isn't referring to an asynchronous cascade.  9 seems like an unreasonably large number of members for most applications, and the docs imply that it's a hard-coded limit.

Comment: Yet, I'm thinking of InnoDB Group Replication. And I know that 9 servers is a large number for most applications. 
But I just want to know what is the consideration of mysql official developers to set the value to 9. Just because 9 is enoughly large? I think the number of servers in a group can be set by programmer.  Can you do more explanation?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the maximum number of servers is nine and I believe that limit is artificially set low as not to overtax the communications protocol between the servers.  There have been requests to increase this number and please put in a feature request at https://bugs.mysql.com with a number you think would be a reasonable number of servers.

Comment: I agree with you idea. Even though I also don't know why the number is nine. I know that more servers means more communications. Maybe it's really just a experience value